# GuardAuthenticator vs Custom controller action for OAuth 2 sign-in flow?

Tags: oauth-2.0, symfony

There are multiple ways to implement OAuth 2 sign-ins in Symfony.

The most straightforward one would be to make two controller actions:

```
class OAuthController extends Controller {

   public function requestAction() {
       ...
       return $this->redirect($facebookAuthrizationUrl);
   }

   public function callbackAction() {
       ...
       $accessToken = ...
       // Validate token
       // Fetch user from Facebook
       $this->signInAsUser(...)
       // Redirect
   }

    public function signInAsUser(UserInterface $user) {
        // This may be an outdated way to sign a user in!
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken(...);
        $this->get("security.context")->setToken($token);
        $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
        $this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);
    }

}
...
```

And then there `GuardAuthenticatorInterface` since Symfony 2.8:

```
class TokenAuthenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator
{
    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    public function supportsRememberMe()
}
```

Which is a simplified way to implement authentication in Symfony, all in one place.

Pros of method 1:
- callback is executed only triggered when needed
- no unnecessary code
Cons:
- feels dirty manually signing in the user
- does not follow the prepared auth flow in Symfony
- not entirely compatible with firewall configuration?

Pros of method 2:
- follows the Symfony flow
- configurable with firewall
- handles errors well
Cons:
- Coupled with controller
- Executed on every anon request
- Feels a bit like an overkill
- Forces a certain code execution path (e.g. getUser function must return a user at that point)

**Which method would be better suited for  OAuth2 flow?**

Comment: I won't presume to say which approach is best but I will say that the first approach works well for me.  And I could never figure out a clean implementation for the second approach.

Comment: Take a look at the ["knpuniversity oauth client bundle"](https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle).

Comment: @Cerad I started off with the first approach, then refactored to GuardAuthenticators. I found an example with API-keys that showed how to limit the authentication to callback URLs only using HttpUtils. Still feel kind of dirty.

Comment: @gp_sflover Thanks, I'll take a look a the code, but ideally, I want to build it myself :) Would you say that KnpUniversity is a good source for quality code samples?

Comment: Well, the bundle was wrote by "weaverryan" (the creator of the Guard system) and I think yes, imho it could be a good source code to inspire you for your own system. PS: I discovered this bundle just before starting to write my own system (following the first approach) but then I decided to use this because it was what I wanted to create.

Comment: @gp_sflover I reverted to the first approach because the second approach felt like a stretch. Controller does only what's needed, I also made and `AbstractAuthenticationController`